# How to use Nginx as a reverse proxy for a blog by configuring nginx.conf w a proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm working to make my site at mysite.com/blog show my tumblr blog without the tumblr URL.

I'm using NGINX and updated by nginx.conf with the following:

```
location /blog {
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;

  gzip on;
  gzip_min_length  1100;
  gzip_buffers     4 8k;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types  text/plain text/html text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  if (!-f $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/blog$     /;
    rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ /$1;
    proxy_pass http://denise-puchol.tumblr.com/;
    break;
  }
}
```

This is failing w/o an error message. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  I have a similar thing I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

[This nginx gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/887026) might help with establishing a reverse proxy for your Tumblr blog. [Definitely worthwhile to subfolder rather than subdomain your blog](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/what-is-a-reverse-proxy-and-how-can-it-help-my-seo) for SEO purposes.

Comment: This worked for me. Make sure you redirect HTTPS to HTTP also because tumblr will load all of its resources over HTTP resulting in a mess on the browser.

Answer (score -1):

How about just using a custom domain name as such:
http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains
?

You may need to alter your url scheme to blog.mysite.com but it has the huge advantage of the traffic going to tumblr's servers directly instad of being proxied through your server.
If your blog receives a lot of traffic, your servers might otherwise be overwhelmed. Also, attackers may abuse your proxy to launch attacks on tumblr which will then appear to be coming from your server.

Comment: I already have that setup and it's bad for seo purposes, would really like to get this working as mysite.com/blog ... see anything wrong on the nginx.conf? thx